# Error using Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ms-access, sqlclient

I'm trying to use Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel to export a table to excel and it gives me error: Can't convert COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type' Microsoft.Office .Interop.Excel._Application '. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
I just try deleted in regedit that id, execute visual studio from /ResetUserData but doesn't works.

Comment: I solved the issue Repair Office 365 e delete other Office instalation i have in my pc.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? 
[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/258475/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-39microsoftoffic.html)

Comment: I repaire the Office 365 in control panel and works fine

Comment: Do keep in mind that when you deploy to a production web server, you have to have office + excel installed. That's not a common setup for a hosted server. If this is your own server, then in most cases the web server when deployed will run as x64 bits, and thus x64 bit version of office in most cases needs to be installed. This works all so easy on your dev box, but then you move to a production server - it will be x64 bits, and so should office. The .net officer inter-op helps but you STILL will need a copy of Excel installed on that web server - and it not a recommned setup.